# Android Spinner created dynamically change selected item background color

Tags: android, spinner

I'm creating a Spinner dynamically like the code below:

```
private void createCoordinationSpinner() {
    TextView tvwCoordination = new TextView(this);
    this.spinnerCoordination = new Spinner(this);

    //Some code to setup textview... 

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsSpinnerCoordination = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    paramsSpinnerCoordination.setMargins(10, 0, 10, 0);

    this.spinnerCoordination.setLayoutParams(paramsSpinnerCoordination);
    this.spinnerCoordination.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_border);
    this.spinnerCoordination.setPrompt("Coordination");
    this.spinnerCoordination.setOnItemSelectedListener(spinnerItemClickListener);

    //Adding both views to an existing LinearLayout, that is possible to have another views, instead of spinner
    linearSchoolCoordination.addView(tvwCoordination, 0);
    linearSchoolCoordination.addView(spinnerCoordination, 1);
    linearSchoolCoordination.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
}

//Thats the line that sets the adapter:
adapterCoordination = new ItemSpinnerAdapter(context, R.layout.coordinationspinnerlayout, arrayCoordination);
```

rounded_border.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <solid android:color="@color/gray_dialog" /> 
    <padding android:left="8dp" 
        android:top="8dp" 
        android:right="8dp" 
        android:bottom="8dp" /> 
    <corners android:radius="20dp" /> 
</shape>
```

coordinationspinnerlayout.xml:

```
<LinearLayout   android:orientation="vertical" 
                android:background="@color/transparent2" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/transparent2"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/transparent2"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" >

            <ImageView  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                        android:id="@+id/imageSpinnerItem" 
                        android:src="@drawable/itemlistviewicon_nochildren" 
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" 
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" 
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/> 

            <TextView   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                        android:id="@+id/tvwSpinnerCoordination" 
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" 
                        android:textSize="16dip" 
                        android:textColor="@color/black" 
                        android:text="TextView" 
                        android:layout_weight="1"/> 

            <ImageView  android:layout_height="20dp" 
                        android:layout_width="20dp" 
                        android:id="@+id/imageSpinnerDownArrow" 
                        android:src="@drawable/spinnerdownarrow" 
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" 
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" 
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/> 
        </LinearLayout> 

        <View   android:background="@color/silver" 
                android:layout_height="1dp" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:id="@+id/linearSpinnerSeparator"/> 

    </LinearLayout> 

</LinearLayout>
```

And finally, the adapter, ItemSpinnerAdapter.java:

```
public class ItemSpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CoordinationData> 
{
    private int tvwID;
    private List<CoordinationData> coordinationList;

    public ItemSpinnerAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<CoordinationData> coordinationList) 
    {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, coordinationList);

        this.tvwID = textViewResourceId;
        this.coordinationList = coordinationList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        ViewHolder holder;
        View view = convertView;

        if (view == null) 
        {
           LayoutInflater layInf = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
           view = layInf.inflate(tvwID, null);

           holder = new ViewHolder();
           holder.tvwDescription = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvwSpinnerCoordination);
           holder.description = coordinationList.get(position).getCoordinationName();

           view.findViewById(R.id.linearSpinnerSeparator).setVisibility(View.GONE);
           view.setTag(holder);

        } 
        else 
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            holder.description = coordinationList.get(position).getCoordinationName();
        }

        if (holder.tvwDescription != null) 
            holder.tvwDescription.setText(holder.description);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        ViewHolder holder;
        View view = convertView;

        if (view == null) 
        {
            LayoutInflater layInf = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = layInf.inflate(tvwID, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.tvwDescription = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvwSpinnerCoordination);
            holder.tvwDescription.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 20);
            holder.description = coordinationList.get(position).getCoordinationName();

            view.findViewById(R.id.imageSpinnerDownArrow).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            view.setTag(holder);

        } 
        else 
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            holder.description = coordinationList.get(position).getCoordinationName();
        }

        if (holder.tvwDescription != null) 
            holder.tvwDescription.setText(holder.description);

    return view;
}

public class ViewHolder 
{
    TextView tvwDescription;
    String description;
}
}
```

adding it to a LinearLayout that already exists in my activity's XML layout file.
Along with my CustomSpinnerAdapter, it works pretty well.
But I still need to change some properties and I'm stucked...
Since my app is using blue texts and backgrounds, I'd like to set the selection of a spinner item highlight color. Its default is orange.

Since I'm developing for API 10, I'm using limited Spinner methods.

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: is that possible to change prompt header background color?

EDIT2: adding further code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long time searching for a solution,

I found out that I **can't set style** or **change its selection color dynamically 'cause of the API version** that I'm developing.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**:

You're using a spinner, so you need to implement `[getDropDownView][1]`.

---

If you want to change the selected color of your View you need to create a Color List Drawable like so

In Colors/list_color.xml

```
<selector>
  <item android:state_selected="true">SomeColor</item>
</selector>
```

in your view

```
<YourView
  android:background="@color/list_color" />
```

See [this resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html) for more info

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it didn't work. I'm already setting a background for it. I tried to set an existing selector as Background Resource.

Comment: Then you need to post all related code, because this is definitely the problem that your havingfrom what I can tell.

Comment: OK, I've just added the adapter and XMLs.

Comment: But getDropDownView is implemented into Adapter's class. Can you be more specific please?

Answer (score 0):

```
take the custum adapter 



mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1,
                    int position, long arg3) {

                _position = position;
                LinearLayout linear_ayout = (LinearLayout)parent.getChildAt(0);
                linear_ayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                TextView tv = (TextView) linear_ayout.getChildAt(0);
                tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                gname_spinner=mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                if (mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("All Groups")) 
                    filItemAdapter("A", ""); 
                    else
                    filItemAdapter("G", mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                Logger.d("******", "not selected");
                 filItemAdapter("A", "");
            }

        });



    MyCustomAdapter custom_adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(
                getApplicationContext(), R.layout.custum_spinner_group,
                group_list);

        mySpinner.setAdapter(custom_adapter);





public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        List<String> group_list;

        public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                List<String> group_list) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, group_list);
            this.group_list = group_list;

        }

        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
        ViewGroup parent) {
            return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
            return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
        }

        public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custum_spinner_group, parent, false);
            TextView text_group = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text_group_name);
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.layout_group_name);
            text_group.setText(group_list.get(position));           

            if (position == _position) {

                layout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.spinner_background));
                text_group.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));

                } else {

                layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                text_group.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.spinner_background));
                }

            Log.d("selected group", ":"+text_group.getText());


            return row;

        }
    }
```